# Show/Hide button based on Select value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

in my Shopify store I have a for loop which will display for each product on the page. For each product, at the bottom, I have a `select` which will determine the billing frequency for each product. There's currently 3 products, if it matters:

```
<select id="ma" class="single-option-selector" name="frequency">
    <option value="">Monthly</option>
    <option value="annual">Annual - 1 Month Free</option>
</select>
```

Then I have 'Continue' buttons which I want to display based on the selected option (either Monthly or Annual)

```
<a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="monthly-btn btn">
    <span id="AddToCartText">Select Plan</span>
</a>

<a href="{{ product.url | within: collection | append: '-annual' }}" class="annual-btn btn">
    <span id="AddToCartText">Select Plan</span>
</a>
```

I'm looking for the right script that will hide and show the buttons based on the currently selected option. Here is what I have now that is not doing anything (I have confirmed by adding the alerts in there - I don't get any alert pop-ups when changing the value)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('.annual-btn').each( function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  });

$('#ma').each( function() { 
  $(this).change( function () {
    var valx = $(this).val()
    if (valx == 'annual') {
      $('.monthly-btn').hide();
      $('.annual-btn').show();
      alert('test');
    } else {
      $('.monthly-btn').show();
      $('.annual-btn').hide();
      alert('test2');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

In addition, I have tried every possible combination of adding .each(), .change() to the function, as well as calling the function directly from the select (so with `onchange="changeFunction();"`). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the 'each()' functions. Also any event listeners added to DOM elements should be wrapped in a

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... code goes here ...});
```

or the shortcut for it:

```
$(function(){ ... code goes here ...});
```

Otherwise the element may not exist when the event listener is added.

And personally I'd use css to hide the annual-btn

```
.annual-btn { display: none; }
```

Then your javascript would be like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#ma').change(function(){
       var opt = $(this).val();
        if(opt == 'annual'){
            $('.monthly-btn').hide();
            $('.annual-btn').show();
        }else{
            $('.monthly-btn').show();
            $('.annual-btn').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qyb83hxv/1/

Comment: So I thought I tried this exact code, but for some reason on the change of the select value, the code is not being called. I tried placing the script both inside and outside of the for loop, but neither worked. The site is: http://store.carumacam.com/collections/service-plans

Comment: check my updated answer. The first issue is that you don't have it wrapped in a $(document).ready(function(){  wrapper. But you also have 3 dropdowns and 3 buttons all with the same classes. So changing one dropdown will change all the buttons unless we modify the code to make them target the specific button.

Comment: Problem #2 is that you have 3 dropdowns with the same ID (id="ma"). That's a big No-No. Using $('#ma') will only return the first element it finds. Where using a class like $('.ma') will return an array of matching elements.

Comment: Here's the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/qyb83hxv/3/ If you check this version: http://jsfiddle.net/qyb83hxv/2/ You will see that only the first dropdown works because they all have the same id.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! However, I thought of a way to give buttons/select different IDs and still none are firing... (I would have been happy if even one was working!)

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! The class I was using was somehow preventing the script from firing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

add on change function to select

```
<select id="ma" onchange="somefunction()" class="single-option-selector" name="frequency">
    <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="annual">Annual - 1 Month Free</option>
</select>


<script>
somefunction(){
 if($("#ma").val() === "monthly"){
   $(".monthly-btn").show();
   $(".annual-btn").hide();
 }else{
   $(".monthly-btn").hide();
   $(".annual-btn").show();
 }
}
</script>
```